# euler challenge 12, why does this python code fail?

Tags: python

The Following code keeps telling me a wrong number and I can't see why, know it's brute force but it should still work... also the number it returns has indeed over 500 divisors, 512 to be exact, help would be much appreciated

```
Number = 1
Count = 2
Found = False
while Found == False:
    Divisors = 0
    if (Number % 2) != 0:
        for i in range(1, int(Number**(1/2)), 2):
            if Number % i == 0:
                Divisors += 1

    else:
        for i in range(1, int(Number**(1/2))):
            if Number % i == 0:
                Divisors += 1

    if Divisors >= 500:
        print (Number)
        Found = True

    else:
        Number += Count
        Count += 1
```

For reference: [Problem 12 from the Euler Challange](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12)

Comment: I think that even if this worked as you intended, you're going to have a problem. Because you're going from 1 to 1/2 the number, you're not going to include the number itself as a divisor. This might not affect your answer, but I thought you'd like to know. Let me know if I'm off here, I'm unfamiliar with python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of divisors of an integer is just the product of (1 + exponent) for each pure power in the factor decomposition of an integer.

As an example: 28 = 2^2 * 7

The powers are 2 and 1, so the number of divisors is `(2+1)*(1+1) = 3*2 = 6`. Easy one

Bigger one: 2047 * 2048 / 2 = 2^10 * 23 * 89

The powers are 10, 1 and 1, so the number of divisors is `11*2*2 = 44`

Easier: 100 = 2^2 * 5^2

The powers are 2, 2 so there are `3*3=9` divisors. The same applies to `36=2^2*3^2`. The only interesting part is the exponents.

So, use any prime factor decomposition (use a sieve, you don't need a primality test) it would be much faster and more reliable than trying each of the possible numbers.

```
def factorize(i):
    # returns an array of prime factors
    whatever

def number_of_divisors(i):
    n = 1
    for v in Counter(factorize(i)).values():
        n *= v + 1
    return n
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what Euler Challenge 12 is, but one obvious issue is the (1/2). If you try typing that in a Python prompt, you'll get 0. The reason why is that it will try to do integer math. I suggest just putting (0.5), or alternatively you could do (1/2.0).

Comment: That depends on whether this is Python 2.x or 3.x. See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/ and http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers

Comment: That's a good point. I still haven't made the transition, so that only occurred to me a second ago.

Answer (score 2):

Your divisor counting method is wrong. 12 has 6 divisors, but your code only counts 2.

Problems:

1. a number often has divisors larger than its square root
2. range doesn't include its upper bound, so you're stopping too early

Comment: The range only going to the square root is certainly a problem.  Perhaps the OP meant to do `Number*(1.0/2)` instead of `**`

Comment: @sberry2A I suspect the OP made a different error, only going to the square root is fine with a small modification. (No explicit correction to not spoil the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

the code you have been write is searching till number**0.5 and it is wrong you must search until number/2
so the corrected answer is like below:

**Note :**  I add some extra code to show the progress. and they are not affect the solution.

**Another Note:** since the Nubmer itself is not counted like in the problem example, I add once to perform that.

```
Number = 1
Count = 2
Found = False
big_Devisor = 0
print "Number   Count   Divisors" 
while Found == False:
    Divisors = 1  # because the Number is itself Devisor
    if (Number % 2) != 0:
        for i in range(1, int(Number/2), 2):
            if Number % i == 0:
                Divisors += 1
    else:
        for i in range(1, int(Number/2)):
            if Number % i == 0:
                Divisors += 1

    if Divisors >= 500:
        print (Number)
        Found = True

    else:
        if Divisors > big_Devisor:
            big_Devisor = Divisors
            print Number,'\t', Count, '\t', Divisors 
        Number += Count
        Count += 1
```